# Ember controller not refreshing template after setting property in promise

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-controllers

I might be doing this horribly wrong, but here goes: I am getting the user from the server, and once it is resolved, I am trying to render the user's name to the page. The login form is actually a popup window based on this: http://www.sociallipstick.com/?p=86

Unfortunately, the template doesn't change at all when I set `userLoggedIn` to `true`. Am I doing something wrong?

```js
App.UserController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    userLoggedIn: false,
    actions: {
        displayLoginForm: function () {
            //displays a login form
        },
        recieveLogin: function (authResult) {
            //hides login form
            var userPromise = this.store.find('user', authResult); // successfully gets user from server (as far as I can tell)
            var self = this;
            userPromise.then(function (user) {
                self.set('model', user);
                self.set('userLoggedIn', true);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<li class="navbar-form">
    {{#if userLoggedIn}}
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">My quizzes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My scores</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    {{else}}
        <button class="btn btn-default" {{action 'displayLoginForm'}}>Login</button>
    {{/if}}
</li>
```

Comment: The code looks good to me, can you send a jsbin reproducing the issue?

Comment: Something I'm thinking is that the navbar might be bound to a different controller... `userLoggedIn` default to undefined (if bound to another controller), which evaluates as false in the `#if` statement. You could add a `{{debugger}}` and check the content property to see if it's bound to the right controller.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it worked in a MWE, so I discovered the error was elsewhere...

Comment: Interesting, so at the end it was indeed a different controller. That was a random guess, I'm glad that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was actually caused by a totally different issue than I thought. The callback from the login script used the [hacky] line to get the controller from a popup outside of Ember:

```js
window.opener.App.__container__.lookup('controller:User').send('recieveLogin', 'USERIDHERE');
```

Unfortunately, this was actually getting a different instance of the controller which was doing nothing...

So, I modified the controller like so:

```js
App.UserController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    userLoggedIn: false,
    actions: {
        displayLoginForm: function () {
            //displays a login form
            /******** THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE ********/
            App.UserController.callback = this;
            /******** THAT WAS THE IMPORTANT LINE ********/
        },
        recieveLogin: function (authResult) {
            //hides login form
            var userPromise = this.store.find('user', authResult); // successfully gets user from server (as far as I can tell)
            var self = this;
            userPromise.then(function (user) {
                self.set('model', user);
                self.set('userLoggedIn', true);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And then I used the marginally less hacky line on the page:

```js
window.opener.App.UserController.callback.send('recieveLogin', 'USERIDHERE');
```

Comment: Not really sure what ettiquette there is about self-answers, but this is what solved it for me. Moral: don't use hacky solutions!

Comment: I think it's fine to answer your own question, after a few days you can even accept it.